# How to concatenate bit by bit in c?

Tags: c, string, matrix, bit-manipulation, bit

I have matrix of '1' and '0' with the dimensions 8x8. I need to store the whole matrix in one **unsigned long long** variable bit by bit. How can i do that?

For example, let's take the matrix of '1' and '0' that is 2x2:
The matrix 2x2:

```
1 0
0 1
```

The variable must contain: 1001 in bits.
The same example, but over the matrix 8x8 and unsigned long long variable.

That's what i've tried to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  unsigned long long result = 0;
  char matrix[8][8]; // lets that the matrix is already filled by '1' and '0'
  for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
   {
     for (j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
      {
        result = result | ((unsigned long long)(matrix[i][j] - '0'));
        result <<= 1;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Is it right? I implemented this nested loop in my algorithm and that didn't work properly.

Comment: Define "didn't work properly".

Comment: `void main` is wrong. `main` should return `int`.

Comment: 'temp = 0;' no matter how many times you shift up 0, it's still 0.

Comment: You want to shift `result`, not `temp` (which you don't need at all...).

Comment: *"Is it right?"* - since the output isn't what you expect, you can probably conclude *no*, it isn't right. Either `temp` or `result` is pointless in this, depending on which one you feel inclined to take the time to remove. Either way, one should go.

Comment: `prog.c:7:8: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)` `prog.c:7:15: error: ‘SIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)` `prog.c:9:11: error: ‘j’ undeclared (first use in this function)` `prog.c:5:22: warning: variable ‘result’ set but not used`

Comment: i've done some edits. This code isnt supposed to print out the value of result after the nested loop without an additional function. My only question is: is the variable "result" contains bits after the loop or not? According to the example in the start topic.

Comment: you want to shift first then place the bit.  and also just do a bit comparison in the string not subtraction.

Comment: if the array has the binary/decimal value 0 and 1 vs ASCII value 0 and 1 then it should work other than being shifted left one because you have the shift last (msbit shifted off the end).  can instead do result <<= 1;  if stuff & 1 then result |= 1;

Comment: Posting compilable code that demonstrates the problem is appreciated.  Code that does not compile lacks clarity and is more difficult.  "didn't work properly."  is not informative.  Post the output seen and expected as well as a [MCVE]

Comment: in addition you have not shown what `SIZE` is. You say it did not work properly, but how do you review the result? That too needs to be in the question. Show some examples.

Comment: I prefer those solutions that shift a mask one position each time round.  Not all hardware has a barrel shifter.

Comment: Well, now the code can't be right because, as old_timer pointed out, you are making an adjustment, then shifting, that means this whole thing will end with... a shift. That means the top bit will be lost and the bottom bit will be clear, *guaranteed*. Follow his advice; shift, then set the bit.

Answer (score 2):

Converting the text representation of an integer into its integer value can be done using `strtoull()`.

```
char buf[sizeof(matrix)+1];
memcpy(buf, matrix, sizeof(matrix));
buf[sizeof(matrix)] = '\0';
result = strtoull(buf, NULL, 2);
```

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Rather than feeling icky because someone asked me to do their homework problem, I prefer the more satisfying feeling of showing someone the better way to solve a technical problem.

Comment: and if instead of `'0'` will be `' '` and instead of `'1'` `'x'`

Comment: @PeterJ_01: No question there is value to understanding fundamentals, but an alternate representation of the input is not an excuse to not use already tested and correctly implemented C library functions. So, for `' '` and `'x'`, transform the input into what is expected by the function, then call the function.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const int mx_size = 8;


int main() {
    unsigned long long result = 0;

    bool  matrix[8][8]; // lets that the matrix is already filled by '1' and '0'
    for (int i =0; i < mx_size; ++i)
        matrix[i][i] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < mx_size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mx_size; j++) {         
            result |= (unsigned long long)matrix[i][j] << (i*mx_size + j);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux here you are

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the code (a bit more

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t convert(char matrix[8][8], int order, char zero)
{
    uint8_t byte;
    uint64_t result = 0;
    for(size_t row = 0; row < 8; row++)
    {
        byte = 0;
        for(size_t column = 0; column < 8; column++)
        {
            byte <<= 1;
            byte |= matrix[row][column] != zero ? 1 : 0; //anything != defined zero char is 1
        }
        if (order)
        {
            result |= (uint64_t)byte << (8 * row);
        }
        else
        {
            result |= (uint64_t)byte << (56 - 8 * row);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    char matrix[8][8] = 
    {
        {'1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'},
        {'0','1','0','1','0','1','0','1'},
        {'1','1','1','0','0','0','1','1'},
        {'0','0','0','1','1','1','0','0'},
        {'1','1','1','1','1','0','0','0'},
        {'0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1'},
        {'1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
        {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1'},
    };

    unsigned long long result = convert(matrix, 0, '0');

    for(size_t index = 0; index < 64; index ++)
        printf("%1d", !!(result & (1ULL << index)));
    printf("\n");
    result = convert(matrix,1, '0');
    for(size_t index = 0; index < 64; index ++)
        printf("%1d", !!(result & (1ULL << index)));
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```